# Changing text in a .txt file using c#

Tags: c#

Basically im trying to save a new password and avatar for my twitter type website.
Any help would be appreciated
My coding is:

```
   string newPasswordString = Server.MapPath("~") + "/App_Data/tuitterUsers.txt";
    string[] newPasswordArray = File.ReadAllLines(newPasswordString);
    string newString = Server.MapPath("~") + "/App_Data/tuitterUsers.txt";
    newString = File.ReadAllText(newString);
    string[] newArray = newString.Split(' ');

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; i++)
            {
                newArray[1] = newPasswordTextBox.Text;
                newArray[2] = avatarDropDownList.SelectedValue;
                newPasswordArray.Replace(" " + Session["Username"].ToString() + " " + Session["UserPassword"].ToString() + " " + Session["UserAvatarID"].ToString() + " ", " " + Session["Username"].ToString() + " " + newPasswordArray[1] + " " + newPasswordArray[2]);
            }

        }
        string newPasswordString = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, newPasswordArray);
        File.WriteAllText(Server.MapPath("~") + "/App_Data/tuitterUsers.txt", newPasswordString);
```

Comment: what is you question ?

Comment: I'd suggest you also look at a database for this kind of stuff. SQL Express / SQLite are free.

Comment: What is wrong with your code? What is happening, any error messages?

Comment: Where and/or what part are you stuck on. Some more clarity on the question your asking please.

Comment: It says system.array does not contain a definition for replace

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly you need to move the

```
 File.WriteAllText(Server.MapPath("~") + "/App_Data/tuitterUsers.txt", newPasswordArray);
```

outside the loop, otherwise you rewrite the file at each loop, but this is not enough, you need also to rebuild the Whole text file

```
 string fileToWrite = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, newPasswordArray);
 File.WriteAllText(Server.MapPath("~") + "/App_Data/tuitterUsers.txt", fileToWrite);
```

EDIT: After the code update and the comment below
The looping is totally wrong as well the rebuilding of the array

```
string userDataFile = Server.MapPath("~") + "/App_Data/tuitterUsers.txt";
string[] userDataArray = File.ReadAllLines(userDataFile);
for(int x = 0; x < userDataArray.Length; x++)
{
    string[] info = userData[x].Split(' ');
    if(Session["Username"].ToString() == info[0])
    {
        userData[x] = string.Join(" ",  Session["UserName"].ToString(),
                                        newPasswordTextBox.Text,
                                        avatarDropDownList.SelectedValue.ToString());
        break;
    }
}
string fileToWrite = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, userDataArray);
File.WriteAllText(Server.MapPath("~") + "/App_Data/tuitterUsers.txt", fileToWrite);
```

**Keep in mind that this works for a limited number of users**.
If you are lucky and you site becomes the new Twitter, you cannot think to use a solution where you read in memory the names of all your users.

Comment: Have updated code above I have to make a twitter based website and I have to have a TextBox which allows me to change a users password and a drop down list to change their profile avatar then I have to overwrite it in the .txt document

Comment: Now your code is unclear. Can you tell me what is the format of the txt file For example (username1,newline,password1,newline,avatar1, newline,username2,newline,password2,newline,avatar2,newline and so on for a maximum number of users)?

Comment: Just all on a single line and just one user?

Comment: multiple lines with 
Username Password Avatar
so in other words there are multiple users

Comment: each new user has a new line

Comment: That has got the Avatar part changing now but the password still stays the same

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, what you're doing is A Bad Idea™.  Given that a web server can have multiple threads in operation, you can't be certain that two threads aren't going to be writing different data at the same time.  The more users you have the larger your user file will be, which means it takes longer to read and write the data, which makes it more likely that two threads will come into conflict.

This is why we use databases for things like this.  Instead of operating on the whole file every time you want to read or write, you operate on a single record.  There are plenty of other reasons to do it to.

That said, if you insist on using a text file...

If you treat each line in the file as a record - a single user's details in this case - then it makes sense to build a class to handle the content of those records, and make that class able to read and write the line format.

Something like this:

```
class UserRecord
{
    public string Name;
    public string Password;
    public string Avatar;

    public UserRecord(string name, string password, string avatar)
    {
        Name = name;
        Password = password;
        Avatar = avatar;
    }

    // static factory method
    public static UserRecord Parse(string source)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(source))
            return null;
        string[] parts = source.Split(',');
        if (parts.Length < 3)
            return null;
        return new UserRecord(parts[0], parts[1], parts[2]);
    }

    // convert to string
    public string ToString()
    {
        return (new string[] { Name, Password, Avatar }).Join(",");
    }
}
```

Adjust the `Parse` method to handle whatever format you're using for the data in the line, and change the `ToString` method to produce that format.

Once you have that working, use it to parse the contents of your file like this:

```
// Somewhere to put the data - a Dictionary is my first choice here
Dictionary<string, UserRecord> users = new Dictionary<string, UserRecord>();

// Don't forget to use 'using' where appropriate
using (TextReader userfile = File.OpenText(userDataFile))
{
    string srcline;
    while ((srcline = userfile.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        UserRecord user = UserRecord.Parse(line);
        if (user != null)
            users[user.Name] = user;
    }
}
```

Then you can access the user's data by username, manipulate it as required, and save it back out whenever you like.

Writing the data back out from a `Dictionary` of users is as simple as:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder;
foreach (UserRecord user in users.Values) 
{
    sb.AppendFormat("{0}\n", user);
}
File.WriteAllText(userDataFile, sb.ToString());
```

Meanwhile, you have a users collection that you can save for future checks and manipulations.

I still think you should use a database though.  They're not hard to learn and they are far better for this sort of thing.